# High Resolution for Tab Bar Icon on retina display

Tags: objective-c, icons

I have a TabBarViewController which include image.png and image@2x.png as TabBar icons. XCode will automatically choose the image for retina and non-retina display. 
I have designed my icon using Photoshop (30x30 and 60x60) but it is not sharpen to display on retina. The information about my icon (png - 8bits, 300dpi)

I saw Amazon - they have a TabBar icon very sharpen and i want to display like that but 60x60, i think it's not enough. Any idea?

Tks in advance!

Comment: 60x60 is correct. Double-check that the images are named correctly and that your 2x version is included in your target. Also, be sure to open the artwork on your computer to make sure that the 2x version is indeed twice the height and width.

Comment: Where you are designating which image to use, make sure you are excluding .PNG, and you simply put 'YourImageName', not 'YourImageName.png' or 'YourImageName@2x.png'